# Insect ID. Montreal, Qc (Canada)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've found this bug in my appartment today and I was wondering what insect it is? Thank you.

[image: The bug]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a "click beetle" ([Coleoptera, Elateridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_beetle)). They have this name because of the loud *click* sound they produce. They are related to fireflies (Lampyridae), and some click beetle species are themselves luminescent.

According to the link above:

> A spine on the prosternum can be snapped into a corresponding notch on the mesosternum, producing a violent ["click"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vew2nzaLerY) that can bounce the beetle into the air.

I don't know about those North American beetles, but in South America I've seen click beetles jumping more than 30cm in the air.

Here is a photo of a click beetle in Montreal, from the [Pest Control Canada](http://pestcontrolcanada.com/5722-2/) website, which looks like your specimen:

[image]

Unfortunately, the entomologist that identified the animal in the photo above didn't narrow it down to Genus or Species.

Comment: Thank you. You "saved" the life of my friends. They thought it was an "American Cockroach"... hahahaha

Comment: The second photo of the question is of a little help in learning the genus this beetle _isn't_; the shape of the scutellum (an oblong plate between the front wings at their base) eliminates the American genera of the subfamily _Cardiophorinae_ (which have the scutellum somewhat resembling a valentine, with the point directed aft).